# How do make a child div absolute?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a search form responsive.Trying to make a `child div absolute` so i can position it at any place i want. Here is the  [**site**](http://thehartcentre.com.au/) , there is a search form with `div` `#search-near`, I want to place it below 2nd navigation and before content.

like this [image]

Comment: Provide a screenshot of how you want.

Comment: check [this](http://www.webdevdoor.com/html-css/css-position-child-div-parent)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `nth-child` selector:

**E.g.:**

```
div:nth-child(1) {

    position: absolute;
    /* More CSS here */
}
```

More informations [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `position: absolute;` will position your the element relatively to the first positioned (non-`static`) ancestor, which is in your case `.right-container`.

Read more about [`absolute` positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)

### So to start:

1. you should remove `position: relative` from the `.right-container`.
2. Remove the `margin-top: -600px` from the `#search-near`
3. Add a `padding-top: 320px` to the `#page-content` to make the `#search-near` some place
4. All these modifications should activate on screensize < [whatever you defined]

### Result:

[image]

### EDIT:

If you have on the page the `#under-slideshow-box`:

1. Then the positioned element should be the `.home-content`. Eg. Add `position: relative` to it (if it isn't already positioned somehow) . The elements on the path until `#search-near` should have default (`static`) positioning.
2. `.home-content` should receive the padding
3. Still important (as in first case as well): `#search-near` should be positioned `absolute` with `top: 0`

### Result:

[image]

Comment: I just realized I did the modifications on [another page](http://thehartcentre.com.au/our-counselling/sex-therapy/), that doesn't contain the `#under-slideshow-box`

Comment: It seems hard to me to set the postion for all pages only home page works :(

Comment: Yes, this is definitely not a generic answer. You should analyze the desired behavior and adapt the hierarchical structure of elements accordingly, so that positioning them will fit your needs. Or you could always go with an uglier solution, just include different styles for each pagetype.